# The called function should be payable but I don't want it to be payable

Tags: solidity, remix, error, payable

I already checked the internet for possible solution but none could help me.

I'm using Solidity ^0.8.7

Below is a function to update a ranking of addresses and is triggered by function transfer(). This ranking is stored in array address[] Ranking;

Now, when I try to transfer tokens I get the error message: "Note: The called function should be payable if you send value and the value you send should be less than your current balance."

These error message disappears when I comment out the rankingUpdate() function. This indicates me that the problem might be in rankingUpdate() function.

I simply don't understand why I get this error message since I don't want to send any Ether and both functions are here to change data inside the smart contract and not to send Ether. Note: The contract address is able to receive tokens with transferfees.

All solutions found in the internet suggested to make function payable and constructor payable to fix this. But this is not my goal since I don't get the logic behind to implement modifier payable when I don't want to receive ether. ... Or is there a reason why this function should receive either f.e. the smart contract to be able to pay gasfee? If so, isn't this gasfee payed by msg.sender? If not, how can I get rid of this error message without having to make it payable?

Thank you in advance for your support

```
function rankingUpdate(address sender, address recipient) 
        private 
        returns(bool) {
            
            if(recipient != address(this)) {  
                if(balanceOf(recipient) >= _minWallet) {
                    bool identical = false;
                    for(uint256 i = 0; i <= Ranking.length.sub(1); i++)
                        if(Ranking[i] == recipient) {
                            identical = true;
                        }
                        else {}
                if(identical == false) {
                    _timestamp[recipient] = block.timestamp;
                    Ranking.push(recipient);
                }
                else {}
                }
            }
            
            if(balanceOf(sender) >= _minWallet) { 
                uint256 x = 0;
                bool identical = false;
                _timestamp[sender] = block.timestamp;
            
                for(uint256 i = 0; i <= Ranking.length.sub(1); i++) {
                    if(Ranking[i] == sender) {
                        x = i;
                        identical = true;
                    }
                    else {}
                }
            
                if(identical == true) {
                    for(uint256 i = x; i <= Ranking.length.sub(2); i++) {
                    Ranking[i] = Ranking[i + 1];
                    }
                Ranking[Ranking.length.sub(1)] = sender;
                }
            }
        
            if(balanceOf(sender) <= _minWallet.sub(1) && sender != address(this)) { 
                uint256 x = 0;
                bool identical = false;
                _timestamp[sender] = 0;
            
                for(uint256 i = 0; i <= Ranking.length.sub(1); i++) {
                    if(Ranking[i] == sender) {
                        x = i;
                        identical = true;
                    }
                    else {}
                }
            
                if(identical == true) {
                    for(uint256 i = x; i <= Ranking.length.sub(2); i++) {
                    Ranking[i] = Ranking[i + 1];
                }
                Ranking.pop();
            }
            else {}
        }
        
        if(block.timestamp >= starttime + 600 && !inPayReward) {
            rewardholder();
        }
        
        return true;
        
    }
```

```
function transfer(address recipient, uint256 amount) 
        initialTransferCheck_(recipient, amount)  // a modifier to check before transfer
        public override returns (bool) {
        
        uint256 TxAmount;
        TxAmount = _calculateAndCollectFee(amount);
            
        move(_msgSender(), recipient, TxAmount);
        emit Transfer(_msgSender(), recipient, TxAmount);
        
        rankingUpdate(_msgSender(), recipient);
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: That error message is misleading, it's shown for every transaction reverted. If you are not using msg.value you should ignore the payable part. Since the transaction reverts there's a bug in the code. You haven't provided enough code to try in remix so I can only guess it may be that out of bounds array access, it could be out of gas because an infinite loop.

Comment: Hi Ismael. Thank you very much. You are right, I went through the code and changed some parts and the error message disapeared. Now it is working.